# How do I programmatically add new row to gridview on button click handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my markup:

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnabc" Text="Hello" 
        onclick="abc_Click" /> <br /> <br />



   <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="test" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" Text = "<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

This is my button click handler:

```
 protected void abc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I can't find any method like `gridview.Rows.Add()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. But you can simply and straightforwardly add a new item to your grid's DataSource and you are done.

Comment: Yes that is the easiest approach but I am trying to add controls programmatically. gridview.Controls.Add(row); where row is instance of GridViewRow works. But this only works for 1st time. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes: when you do that, it does not go to ViewState, so it gets lost. You'd have to keep doing it for every postback. Seriously, you are better off dealing with the DataSource. You do realize that, say, an object list can be a DataSource, right? Maybe you can explore that.

Comment: Yes I do realize that you can setup List and according to your template of your gridview it will layout items. As I said easiest and the best solution! but I was just trying something new but I understand it is not possible. Thanks.

Comment: Technically, it is possible. It just takes a lot more work than managing a simple custom objects list. Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a row to the datasource object, and then rebind the GridView.